# Alt+ 3 doesn't work after Wmpkeys (windows media player plug-in) installed

Tags: plugins, hotkeys, windows-media-player

Alt+1, Alt+2, Alt+3  .... combos doesn't work after I installed wmpkeys which gives media player a global hotkey ability. If you guys could overcome this problem let me know please.

Edit : This is my edited combinations, but I must say Alt buttons wasn't already working before I changed the shortcuts..

[image: [My shortcut combination]]

Comment: Have you changed the hotkeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Media Player Plus!](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) is a more recent plug-in that also allows you to configure global hotkeys for WMP.

Comment: I've also installed that and solved this issue.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Source [WMPKeys: Adds Global Hot Keys To Windows Media Player](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/wmpkeys-adds-global-hot-keys-to-windows-media-player/)

> To change hotkeys go to Options -> Plug-ins, select Wmpkeys Plugin and
>   click Properties  to open the Settings for WMP Keys. There you can
>   input any combination of keys for different functions.

[image]

Source [WMP Keys](http://wmpkeys.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

The default hotkeys do **not** seem to include <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>

**Note**

According to the [project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wmpkeys/files/?source=navbar) WMPKeys is **Beta** software. It has not been updated since **2008-05-18**

In addition, there is an open [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/wmpkeys/bugs/2/):

> When wmp is open with this plugin enabled some keys don't work... Till
>   now i've found 3: @ (ALT GR + 2), £ (ALT GR + 3), § (ALT GR + 4). I
>   just can't write them anywhere, as soon as i desable the plugin it
>   gets to its normal state. My OS is Windows 7 (x64)

**Conclusion**

It is old and buggy. You are probably better off finding an alternative if it is not working for you.

Comment: Thx For your answer David but I know how to use it but it disables my Alt+Number key button for example I cannot write "#"

Comment: @ProjectMayhem "#" is "shift"+"3" not "alt"+"3" ?

Comment: I am not using Netherland keyboard dude :)

Comment: I'm not either. US keyboard here. What keyboard are you using?

Comment: Turkish keyboard, just buttons place are different, this shouldn't cause the problem.

Comment: Ok, see my answer update.

Comment: Yees I'd better find a new global shortcut plugin thx for your effords buddy.